# Check SelectedIndex matches on multiple selects

Tags: jquery

Question : Whats the easiest / most efficient way of determining if multiple select lists have the same `selectedIndex` ?

Background Info : 
I have several (up to 200) select lists on a page - all with the class `tariff` and i need to check that they all have the same `selectedIndex`

My first approach was to loop using each and record the previous value - making sure that every select matched - but it just seems inefficient .. for example

```
var tariffSelected;
var first = true;
$('.tariff').each(function() {
   if (first) {
      // store first value
      tariffSelected = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
      first = false;
   }
   if (tariffSelected !== $(this).prop('selectedIndex')) {
      // they don't match
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just check that the number of selects is the same as the number of selects with a selectedIndex matching the first select, e.g.:

```
var allTariffs = $('.tariff');
var indexToMatch = allTariffs.eq(0).prop('selectedIndex');

var matchingTariffs = allTariffs.filter(function () {
    return $(this).prop('selectedIndex') === indexToMatch;
});

var allMatch = allTariffs.length === matchingTariffs.length;
```

Comment: +1 just what I was looking for ... thanks (will accept when timer expires)

Comment: And you must return from filter method  ;)  `return $(this).prop('selectedIndex') === indexToMatch;`

Comment: Thanks for the catches, doing too much at once :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/q89Tf/

```
var s = $("select.tariff");
var firstVal = $("select").first().prop("selectedIndex");
var ss = $('select').filter(function() {
    return this.selectedIndex === firstVal;
}).length === s.length;
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted - seems to work fine ... +1 thanks

Comment: I downvoted this because it was exactly the same as my answer (with worse variable names) 17 minutes afterwards.

Comment: sorry, I honestly didn't copy you, I started working on it and didn't refresh the page before posting it.